# Parce qu'il y aura un air frais

Tags: usage, formulation-idiomatique

Je voudrais savoir si la phrase suivante est correcte et se dirait couramment :

> *Je vais emporter un pull parce qu'à la météo, on a dit que ce soir, il y aura un air frais.* ( pour: cela va se rafraîchir ).

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas utiliser l'autre option que tu mentionnes ("cela va se raffraîchir") et qui est, elle, idiomatique. "Il y aura un air frais" ne l'est pas, dans aucun contexte auquel je pense...

Answer (score 3):

On dira plutôt:

> il va faire frais
>
> l'air va se rafraîchir
>
> ça va se rafraîchir

Si on dit "il y a un air frais", on ne parlera pas de l'air perceptible dehors par tous, mais éventuellement d'un souffle d'air qui passe à un endroit précis, par exemple: "à l'entrée de ce magasin, il y a un air frais, parce que l'air conditionné y est installé et y souffle particulièrement fort".

Answer (score 2):

On ne peut jamais dire « il y aura un air frais » ; il me semble que l'on n'entend jamais dire cela ; occasionnellement, quelqu'un pourra dire « Il y a un petit air frais. » ou « Il y avait un petit air frais. ».

Ci-dessous se trouvent des façons  courantes de dire la phrase ;

- Je vais emporter un pull parce qu'à la météo on a dit que ce soir **il allait faire frais**.
- Je vais emporter un pull parce qu'à la météo on a dit que ce soir **le temps allait se rafraichir**.

On peut dire aussi ceci :

« Je vais emporter un pull parce qu'à la météo on a dit que ce soir **l'air sera frais**. ».

P.S. Je ne vois pas trop la nécessité des virgules dans cette phrase et je les ai supprimées.

Comment: Cette réponse me paraît correcte, si ce n'est le troisième exemple "Il y aura de l'air frais" qui n'est pas du tout idiomatique.

Comment: @LaurentS. Ça me semblait correct, mais je ne peux pas être trop affirmatif là-dessus. Dans le doute il vaut mieux s'abstenir, comme le dicton l'enseigne ; je vais l'enlever.

Answer (score 1):

You could say :

> - "Je vais emporter un pull parce qu'à la météo, on a dit que ce soir, le fond de l'air sera frais..."

This means that even though it's warm in the daytime, when the sun sets, it'll be unexpectedly and treacherously chilly and you might want to wear something to keep you warm and not catch a cold.